# Break up permutation cycle to cycles of length 3

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, discrete-mathematics

Is it possible to break up a permutation cycle to cycles of length 3?
For ex: There's a permutation cycle (12345). Can we represent it in cycles of 3, given that parity of permutation is even and can be broken up into adjacent transpositions?

Answer (score 0):

The alternating group $A_n$ is generated the subgroup generated by $3$-cycles.

Therefore, a permutation is a product of $3$-cycles iff it is even.

To write an even permutation as a product of $3$-cycles, first write it as a product of an even number of transpositions, then apply the formulas below to each pair of consecutive transpositions, adapting them if you use a different composition order.

$(ab)(cd) = (acb)(acd)$

$(ab)(ad) = (adb)$

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1868840/589

Comment: Yes, but is there an algorithm that can generate 3-cycles?

Comment: Also, in the answer, are you following right-first or left-first in applying permutations?

Comment: @TheJoker, I'm not sure about the order, but it doesn't matter, though the formulas will be just a little different.